# Proof help- the set $\{ P \in \mathbb{P}^N(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}) : H(P) \leq C, [\mathbb{Q}(P):\mathbb{Q}] \leq d] \}$ is finite ((Heights in Silverman)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I have a doubt in the following theorem (Silverman AEC)

[image: Theorem 5.11]

Doubt 1: Why is the expression for $$H_{\mathbb{Q}(P)}(P) \geq max_{ 0 \leq i \leq N} \Big(\prod_{v \in \mathbb{Q}(P)} max\{|x_i|_v,1\}^{n_v} \Big)?$$

I tried it for $N = 0$ case (to see why it could be true): then LHS simplifies to $\prod_{v \in \mathbb{Q}(P)} |x_0|_v^{n_v}$ while RHS (the expression on the right of $\geq $) equals $\prod_{v \in \mathbb{Q}(P)} max\{|x_0|_v,1\}^{n_v}$.

We can split this product into those $v \in \mathbb{Q}(P)$ for which $|x_0|_v \geq 1$ and $|x_0| \leq 1$. But by the choice of homogeneous coordinates that at least one $x_j=1$, we have LHS = RHS here.

And how do I generalise this reasoning? (I guess that wouldn't be hard once I have at least $N =0,1$ case down)

Doubt 2: The book says it is sufficient to prove consider the case $N =1$. How do I show that?

For any $N$, and fixed $C, d$, by $N=1$ case we have $H_{\mathbb{Q}(x_i)}(x_i) \leq C$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(x_i):\mathbb{Q}] \leq d$ for all $ i \in \{ 0, 1, ... , N\}$.

Then $max_{ 0 \leq i \leq N} H_{\mathbb{Q}(x_i)}(x_i) \leq C^d$ and $max_{0 \leq i \leq N} [\mathbb{Q}(x_i): \mathbb{Q}] \leq d$.

Am I on the right track? Would really appreciate any help with this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doubt 1: The inequality he wants to show is
$$H(P) = \prod_v \max_i\{|x_i|_v\}^{n_v} \geq \max_i\left\{\prod_v \max\{|x_i|_v,1\}^{n_v}\right\}$$

On the right hand side, let's say the maximum is achieved by $i=k$ fixed. So now the RHS is just
$$\prod_v \max\{|x_k|_v,1\}^{n_v}$$

And this we can compare termwise to the LHS. So we reduce to showing that
$$\max_i \{|x_i|_v\} \geq \max\{x_k,1\}^{n_v}$$

Recall that we normalized $P$ so that one of the $x_i$'s is $1$, and $|1|_v = 1$ for all $v$. So on the left, the set we take the maximum over includes both $1$ and $x_k$, but also the other $x_i$'s so it can only be bigger than the maximum of $1$ and $x_k$.

p.s. the $N=0$ case won't help much because $\mathbb P^0$ doesn't really exist, and if it did it would probably have just 1 point.

Doubt 2: as it says in the book, the reduction to $N=1$ is essentially done by applying that case to each (dehomogenized) projective coordinate.

If we show that there are only finitely many choices of each $x_i$ in this setting, then we are done, because then there are only finitely many choices for $P$.

The $N=1$ case can be applied to the points $[x_i:1]$ in $\mathbb P$ if we show that $(1)$ $H([x_i:1])$ is bounded and $(2)$ that the degree of $\mathbb Q([x_i:1])$ is bounded.

(1) By the first inequality, 
$$H(P) \geq \max H(x_i)$$
so each $H([x_i:1])$ is bounded by the same bound on $H(P)$.

(2) Observe that after normalizing $P$ to make one of its coordinates $1$, we have essentially dehomogenized it, and in particular $\mathbb Q([x_i:1]) = \mathbb Q(x_i) \subseteq \mathbb Q(P)$, and so if the degree of the latter is bounded, so is the degree of the former.

Thus for each coordinate $x_i$, there are only finitely many choices, and hence finitely many points $P$.

I don't quite follow your work for this case. I can see that you have extra exponents associated to the degrees of $\mathbb Q(x_i)$, but remember that the global height is defined so that thsoe don't appear. The inequality also seems like it is in the wrong direction, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first part is clear. For the second, I think I'm missing some basic logic reasoning to understand why $N =1$ is sufficient. Doesn't saying showing the required is sufficient for $ N=1$ means that we can get the general $N$ case from it? (That's what I've made attempts in above).

Comment: Yes and that's what Silverman shows (and I explain above). You get the result for general $N$ by applying the result for $N=1$ to each coordinate. So after you prove it for $N=1$ and you believe in the reduction from general $N$ to $N=1$ you are done. Can you identify a particular spot in that reduction which confuses you?

Comment: Oh, you mean for each $x_i$(dehomogenized), we can show that there are only finitely many choices for it (the second paragraph in the proof) and thus there are only finitely many choices for all the homogenous coordinates of $P \in \mathbb{P}^N$ as well?

Comment: Yes exactly!! And a dehomogenized $x_i$ is the same as the point $[x_i : 1]$ in $\mathbb P^1$, so we use that case to check that there are in fact finitely many of them.

Comment: I think I understand this now. Thank you very much!